# BitmapFactory : "decode returned false" for internal image files extracted from zip?

Tags: android, image, decode, bitmapfactory

Need to display images downloaded and extracted from a zip into the "/files" directory of the app. the images are getting in there properly as far as I can tell - I am able to extract them from the emulator and view/open them from my desktop. but every attempt, every variation of code I have found and tried so far has failed (Tag: skia / Text: --- decoder->decode returned false).

My latest construct, which does work for image files downloaded separately and uncompressed :

```
String imgFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "myImage.jpg").getAbsolutePath();

        ImageView myImageView = new ImageView(this); 
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try{

            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile);
            myImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

        } finally{

            mainLayout.addView(myImageView);
        }
```

And here is the construct I am using to handle the zip extraction. I assume this is where the problem lies but I am clueless as to what I could possibly do differently and to what effect:

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(fis);
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(zis, 8192);
ZipEntry ze;

while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null){
    File dest_file = new File(getFilesDir(), ze.getName());
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(getFilesDir() + "/" + ze.getName());
    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(fout, 8192);
    byte b[] = new byte[1024];
    int n;

    while ((n = in.read(b,0,1024)) >= 0) {
        out.write(b,0,n);
    }

    for (int c = zis.read(); c != -1; c = zis.read()) { 
        fout.write(c); 
    }

    zis.closeEntry();
    fout.close();
}
zis.close();
fis.close();
```

At a terrible standstill here. Appreciate any solutions/suggestions.